# No package MYSQL-community 5.7*

Tags: mysql, installation, centos, centos6

am very new to Cent Os. I have to install mysql on my cent os 6.9 version.

I have tried almost all commands,But am getting one or the other issue while installing

`yum localinstall https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql57-community-release-el6-11.noarch.rpm`

if i use above command am getting **Nothing to do**

I know there are many answers,But none of the commands helping me to solve this.

Can someone please help me with this issue and to install mysql 5.* version on centos 6.9.

image links

https://i.stack.imgur.com/t0XEN.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGkvn.png

Thank you

Please help to solve this

Comment: Try with this tutorial https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/centos-lamp-server-apache-mysql-php

Comment: Thank you @NazmulHasan , I need mysql support for java,not php